# GridView RowCommand is not updating the control value

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have a LinkButton in Gridview which popups up a jQuery popup box for delete confirmation. Besides I have triggered Gridview RowCommand which should assign value to textbox which is within the jQuery popup box. The problem here is that the popup box appears after the LinkButton click but the RowCommand event does not assign value to the textbox. In fact textbox gets back to its old default value.

I googled this problem too much but could not get the right solution. Below is my code and any help is extremely appreciable.

```
    //The code behind GridView_RowCommand event
    protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        string arguments = e.CommandName + " - " + e.CommandArgument.ToString() + " - " + e.CommandSource.ToString();
        if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
        {
            txt.Text = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
        }
    }

    //Page Source
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
         <ContentTemplate>
              <div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal">
                   <h1>Delete</h1>
                   <p>This will guide you through the delete process</p>
                   <asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                   <p><asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" /></p>
                   <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>                       
              </div>

              <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="RBUEntityDataSource" CssClass="gridview" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" EnableViewState="True">
                   <Columns>
                   <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Id" />
                   <asp:BoundField DataField="Region" HeaderText="Region" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Region" />
                   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Update">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                             <asp:LinkButton ID="lbUpdate" runat="server" CommandName="Update" OnClick="lbUpdate_Click">Update</asp:LinkButton>
                         </ItemTemplate>
                   </asp:TemplateField>
                   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
                         <ItemTemplate>
                             <asp:LinkButton ID="lbDelete" class="big-link" data-reveal-id="myModal" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>'>Delete</asp:LinkButton>
                         </ItemTemplate>
                   </asp:TemplateField>
              </Columns>
         </asp:GridView>
         <asp:EntityDataSource ID="RBUEntityDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="name=ChemonicsDBEntities" DefaultContainerName="ChemonicsDBEntities" EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="RegionalBusinessUnits" Select="it.[Id], it.[Region]" OrderBy="it.[Id] asc" Where="it.[DeletedBy] = 0">
          </asp:EntityDataSource>
     </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: @HassanNisar How to do that. Could you please guide me?

Answer (score 0):

> While working with asp:updatepanel we have to maek some changes.And if you are using JQuery then find your jQuery function
>
> You have to add a load() function  which will add the End Request
>   event using the Page Request Manager and will register the jquery
>   function (Here jsFunctions)

Like this

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function load() {
            Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(jsFunctions);
        }
        function jsFunctions() {            
                $("#btnClick").click(function () {                    
                    alert("Alert");
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Finally

```
<body onload="load()">
```